# What is the difference between ConvLSTM and CNN LSTM?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory

What will be the difference when used for video classification? Will they yield different results or are they the same fundamentally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing a bit of research I found that the LSTM whose gates perform convolutions is called ConvLSTM.

The term CNN LSTM is loose and may mean stacking up LSTM on top of CNN for tasks like video classification

[Reddit thread discussing this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/5qt7oh/d_what_is_the_difference_between_using_the/)